# C++ float scanf input number

Tags: c

I use Bloodshed DevC++ to compile this code.
But I get problem with scanf float number.
And I don't want get decimal type, but the result must in float type, 
But the result always be 0.000000.

This is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

main()

{
    float A, B, C;
    B = 3.14;

    C = (4*B*A*A);

    printf (" Enter value of A : "); scanf("%f", &A);
    printf ("\n");
    printf (" So, the result is : %f", C);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

And result is:
[Float.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdXcm.jpg)

```
Enter value of A : 22.45

 So, the result is : 0.000000

--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.235 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It would be better if anyone help me, Thanks :)

Comment: So the computer is mystic and knows `A` before you type it - therefore knowing the value of `C` from this equation `C = (4*B*A*A);`

Comment: `A` is uninitialized

Comment: PS: check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: This is just appalling:(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because preofessional and/or enthusiast programmers are expected to know that, unless execution flow is explicitly modified, code is executed from top to bottom, not upwards or sideways.

Comment: @MartinJames That's a very valid downvote reason, but I don't think it makes any sense as a close reason. Remember [a close vote is not a super-downvote](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one).

Comment: Sorry for my bad question Sir :( because I am just student that get this homework.

Comment: @lxrec missing effort is a reason for close. I mean there are just few permutations of those few lines of code and most of them do the right thing. This really looks like a "I just immedialty post it on SO, instead of using my own brain" question (no offense to the OP ;)

Comment: Don't post images of text! And C is not C++. Use the tag for the language you use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `C = (4*B*A*A);`, this doesn't mean that `C` will *always* contains what that expression evaluates to.  It means that you're modifying `C` based on the value of that expression *at that moment*.

So changing `A` after this point has no effect on the value of `C`.  And since `A` is uninitialized, this results in **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**, meaning the results are not necessarily predictable.

You need to first read in the value of `A`, *then* modify `C` based on the current values of `A` and `B`:

```
printf (" Enter value of A : "); scanf("%f", &A);
C = (4*B*A*A);
printf ("\n");
printf (" So, the result is : %f", C);
printf ("\n");
```

To do what you *though* your original code would do, you'd need to define a function that will calculate the value of `C` when you call it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int C(int A, int B)
{
    return 4*B*A*A;
}

int main()
{
    float A, B;
    B = 3.14;

    printf (" Enter value of A : "); scanf("%f", &A);
    printf ("\n");
    printf (" So, the result is : %f", C(A,B));
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the "result" before you ask for input:

```
float A, B, C;
B = 3.14;

C = (4*B*A*A);   //  What value has A here? Probably 0 !!

printf (" Enter value of A : "); scanf("%f", &A);  // This has no influence
                                                   // whatsoever on the 
                                                   // value of C
printf ("\n");
printf (" So, the result is : %f", C);
printf ("\n");
```

I am not sure about C (question was tagged C++ before), but I guess `A` gets initialized to `0`, thus the result is indeed exactly `0`.

PS: a kind compiler would issue a warning, something like "Warning: variable A is used uninitialized."